# Graylog search based on variable

Tags: variables, search, graylog

Let's say I have a three inputs (or streams) with logA ,logB and logC

logA

```
This is log example val1 val2
```

logB

```
This is log example val2
```

logC

```
This is log example val2
```

I'm looking for a way to configure graylog in a way to search these three logs using val2 correlation with val1

Use case:

```
I input val1
graylog finds all (it might be more than one) connected val2
graylog searches all input/streams using val2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with Graylog out of the box, but you could write a script utilizing the Graylog REST API.